# std::ifstream failed to open file under c:\program files(x86)

Tags: c++, windows

I have administrative permission and I tried to open the file under c:\program files(x86) on windows. std::ifstream failed to open and error number trowed as 2. If I copy the same file into some other location, its working fine.

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <cerrno>        
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs1("C:\\Program Files(x86)\\somefile.html");
    if (ifs1.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "File opened\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "File open failed. error number = " << errno << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is it because of permission issue?

Comment: It's `Program Files (x86)` not `Program Files(x86)`. You missed a whitespace.

Comment: @DimChtz - if that's an answer, please post it as such. (Ps. I think it is an excellent answer, and very likely correct.)

Comment: @Robᵩ If all it is is a missing space then instead of answering it should be closed voted.

Comment: @NathanOliver Well, that's why I didn't answer it in the first place. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: @DimChtz Don't worry about it.  You can't anymore anyways as it is accepted.

Comment: Could be a typo in OP's question too. Pretty sure that, by default, the administrator doesn't have access to write in the program files directories. On my system at least, only TrustedInstaller can do that.

Comment: @DimChtz That's why it's discouraged. I just slows down the process such useless stuff is removed from the site, and encourages users to ask such kind of questions.

Comment: I stand corrected. Sorry, @DimChtz for steering you the wrong way.

Comment: @Robᵩ No problem. My mistake actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because of this:

```
"C:\\Program Files(x86)\\somefile.html"
```

which actually should be:

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\somefile.html"
```

You just missed a whitespace.

Comment: If the answer to a question is "You made a typo", please flag to close the question instead of answering it.